# Add a scrollbar for text object inside frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame which has a text object inside it. How do I add a vertical scrollbar that controls the text object. The scrollbar should be on the right side..

```
inputFrame = Frame(bg='#d9d9d9')
inputFrame.pack()
inputEntryImg = PhotoImage(file=resource_path("inputEntry.png"))
inputEntryBg = mainWindowCanvas.create_image(400.0, 168.5, image=inputEntryImg)
inputEntry = Text(inputFrame, bd=0, bg="#d9d9d9", highlightthickness=0, font='calibri', 
pady=10)
inputEntry.pack(padx=(0, 10), pady=10)
inputFrame.place(x=41.0, y=83, width=718.0, height=169)
```

Thankyou.

Comment: and what exactly is the catch?

Comment: There must be thousands of examples on the internet and in tkinter tutorials. It’s not clear why you need our help.

Comment: @СергейКох no catch!

Comment: @BryanOakley I couldn't find anything... maybe you could send me a link?

Comment: You can simply use [tkinter ScrolledText](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html) instead of `Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(inputFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=inputEntry.yview)

scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

inputEntry.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Comment: It doesn't show for some reason... Would you know why?

Comment: I added the code and it didn't error, it just doesn't show.

Comment: Maybe the frame is not wide enough to show the scrollbar. Try removing the `width` option in `inputFrame.place(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add a vertical scrollbar that controls the text object. The
> scrollbar should be on the right side..

Try this. I did not add `PhotoImage`. You can add it by yourself.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

inputFrame = tk.Frame(bg='#d9d9d9')
inputFrame.pack()

#inputEntryImg = tk.PhotoImage(file=resource_path("inputEntry.png"))
#inputEntryBg = mainWindowCanvas.create_image(400.0, 168.5, image=inputEntryImg)

inputEntry=tk.Text(inputFrame, height=10, width=50)

scrollBar= tk.Scrollbar(inputFrame, command=inputEntry.yview, orient="vertical")
scrollBar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

inputEntry.grid(row=0,column=0)
inputEntry.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for scrollbar with text:

[image]